# Gnome error when installing Desktop Environment on SLES 12

Tags: xorg, vnc, suse, x11vnc

I am trying to install the graphical interface on a SLES 12 server but after following the following guides I get a dark screen and a cursor. In the errors I find the following message:

```
gnome-session-failed:4760
```

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_12&p=desktop&f=1
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_12&p=desktop&f=2